# Where does XFCE store the keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: xubuntu, shortcut-keys, xfce

I'd like to backup my keyboard shortcuts but I couldn't find where Xfce stores them.

Comment: Do you mean the file, or what application allows you to set and change them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The configured keyboard shortcuts should be in:

```
/home/username/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml
```