# Syntax for keyboard shortcuts

Tags: shortcut-keys, xfce, syntax

What is the proper syntax for adding keyboard shortcuts in xfce4?
From the existing shortcuts, I noticed that every shortcuts command is not the same. Different kind of syntax is used for different functions.
Can anybody tell me the general rules?

```
echo -e "Version $(lsb_release -a)" && echo -e "Session: $DESKTOP_SESSION" && echo -e "Desktop: $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP"

No LSB modules are available. 
Version Distributor ID: Ubuntu 
Description: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS 
Release: 18.04 
Codename: bionic 
Session: xfce 
Desktop: XFCE
```

Comment: What is the exact problem you're facing? And which distro are you using? What is the output of `echo -e "Version $(lsb_release -a)" && echo -e "Session: $DESKTOP_SESSION" && echo -e "Desktop: $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP"`?

Comment: No LSB modules are available.
    Version Distributor ID: Ubuntu
    Description: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
    Release: 18.04
    Codename: bionic
    Session: xfce
Desktop: XFCE

Comment: So what about your actual question? Which keyboard shortcut do you want to add/change? And what difficulty are you facing?

Comment: It is not actually a difficulty. I just wanted to know the general syntax to make a keyboard shortcut. Question is not specifically designed for a particular application. If it is very much complex, experts can share links from where I can learn it.

Answer (score 0):

There are several resources available and these can be found by searching the internet for *xfce4 keyboard shortcuts* or something more specific.

The primary source is [the FAQ](https://wiki.xfce.org/faq#keyboard).

Another good resource is the [XFCE forum](https://forum.xfce.org). Search the site for what you need. Sign up and post questions there!

Obviously, searching Ask Ubuntu is useful as well! For example: [Where does XFCE store the keyboard shortcuts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866728/where-does-xfce-store-the-keyboard-shortcuts)

More resources include other Stack Exchange sites and forums for distros that offer XFCE as a desktop environment and blogs or tech sites:

- [Change xfce4 keyboard shortcuts](https://superuser.com/questions/1186696/change-xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts)
- [xfce4: is there a list of commands for keyboard shortcuts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42526711/xfce4-is-there-a-list-of-commands-for-keyboard-shortcuts)
- [Change global keyboard shortcuts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44643/change-global-keyboard-shortcuts)
- [Custom Keyboard Shortcuts at the MX Linux forum](https://forum.mxlinux.org/viewtopic.php?f=104&t=47779).
- [XFCE:Making Keyboard Shortcuts for Frequently Used Applications](https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php?title=XFCE:Making_Keyboard_Shortcuts_for_Frequently_Used_Applications)
- [Adding xfce4 Keyboard Shortcuts for Clementine or Spotify](https://rohanverma.net/blog/2017/05/20/xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts-for-clementine/)

A caution is that you should keep in mind that XFCE, even though it's relatively stable, is *evolving*. Applications that used GTK2 in the past may now use GTK3. That can have consequences on how keyboard shortcuts work. So make sure you refer to sources that deal with *your* version of XFCE.

Also remember that XFCE, and other desktop environments, have separate graphical user interfaces to set shortcuts for applications and shortcuts for manipulating your window manager which, in XFCE, is *xfwm4*.

---

Most of the above deals with applications installed from the repositories or, in the case of Ubuntu and its flavors, from [personal private archives](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/addremove-ppa.html.en).

However, we now have [AppImages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/774490/what-is-an-appimage-how-do-i-install-it), [snaps](https://askubuntu.com/a/761290/248158) and [flatpaks](https://flatpak.org/) as well. Creating shortcuts to launch such applications maybe different. Again, asking questions about specific applications will probably get you the answers you need.